# ol/controls/default not a function in OpenLayers 7.1

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6, openlayers-7

With OpenLayers 6.15.1, I can use the following code in my map options:

```
controls: ol.control.defaults({
    zoom: true,
    attribution: true,
    rotate: false
}),
```

With OpenLayers 7.1, this does not work anymore. I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: ol.control.defaults is not a function

Does anyone could explain to me what I have to change in my code?
I have found nothing explicit in the OpenLayers official documentation online about ol/control/defaults that could explain this error.

Comment: try ol.control.defaults.defaults

Answer (score 11):

See [ol.interaction.defaults is not a function #14020](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/14020) (and [Legacy build 'control.defaults' and 'interaction.defaults' broken #14078](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/14078))

from [that issue](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/14020):

> - ahocevar : It should be ol.interaction.defaults.defaults now.
> - hweri69 : Similarly it is now ol.control.defaults.defaults

The code was moved to its own moddule to resolve a circular dependency, see: [Remove circular dependency #13967](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/13967)

(per comment by @MoonE)

**code snippet:**

```js
//
// Create map, giving it a rotate to north control.
//

const map = new ol.Map({
  controls: ol.control.defaults.defaults({
    zoom: true,
    attribution: true,
    rotate: false
  }),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({ // TileLayer({
      source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    }),
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 3,
    rotation: 1,
  }),
});
```

```css
.map,
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Default Controls</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.1.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.1.0/ol.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <!-- Pointer events polyfill for old browsers, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/elm-pep@1.0.6/dist/elm-pep.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```